# Flutter/Riverpod: Call method within StateNotifier from another StateNotifier

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, riverpod

How can I call the method of one `StateNotifier` from another `StateNotifier`? I want to call `addNewHabit` (in the top class) from `submitData` (in the lower class).

Here are the bodies of the classes:

```dart
class HabitStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Habit>> {
  HabitStateNotifier(state) : super(state ?? []);

  void startAddNewHabit(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) {
          return NewHabit();
        });
  }

  //this one right here
  void addNewHabit(String title) {
    final newHabit = Habit(title: title);
    state.add(newHabit);
  }

  void deleteHabit(String id) {
    state.removeWhere((habit) => habit.id == id);
  }
}
```

and

```dart
class TitleControllerStateNotifier
    extends StateNotifier<TextEditingController> {
  TitleControllerStateNotifier(state) : super(state);

  void submitData() {
    if (state.text.isEmpty) {
      return;
    } else {
      //call 'addNewHabit' from above class
    }
  }
}
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Technically, not a recommended pattern to use as StateNotifiers are controllers and you shouldn't really be calling controllers inside controllers.

But this is pretty easy to accomplish as you can read other providers inside a provider.

```dart
final habitProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) => HabitStateNotifier());

final userControllerProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) {
  return UserController(
   
    habitProvider : ref.read(habitProvider),
  );
});
```

And then use the reference and call

```dart
class TitleControllerStateNotifier
    extends StateNotifier<TextEditingController> {
  TitleControllerStateNotifier(state, HabitStateNotifier habitProvider) :
  habit = habitProvider, 
  super(state);

  final HabitStateNotifier habit;


  void submitData() {
    if (state.text.isEmpty) {
      return;
    } else {
      habit.addNewHabit(state.text);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What would the recommend be to accomplish this?

Comment: Why don't you remove the second Statenotifer and have only one instead? anyway, all you're doing is accessing the `TextControllerEditor`. so call the submitData within HabitNotifier and then call it? @wolfeweeks

Answer (score 0):

Set up a StateNotifierProvider (from Riverpod), which will give you back a StateNotifier after running the create callback.  This callback has a `(ref)` parameter on which you can call `ref.read` and `ref.watch` to fetch other providers in either non-depending or depending mode.